# How to view more content on terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I need to print a list of 20,000 words, but I can only view a small part of it, I can't see the beginning part of the list. How to view more content? I am using X-terminal on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just type the following when in console

```
less <yourfilename>
```

and then use up and down arrow keys; also the following could be useful:

- q to quit
- SHIFT + g to go to end of file
- gg to go to start of file
- (line number)gg to go to particular line number

Comment: Sorry, I execute my file with python. This can view the file before it was executed.

Comment: In this case you can do 'python <yourscriptname> | more' and the same keyboard shortcuts will apply as above, as the output will be capture by piping(using |) to more

Comment: In this mode, can I go to a particular result line?

Comment: I find I can type g + num  + Enter to go to particular line in the result.

Comment: Yes sorry when using more you can do 'g + num + Enter', also you could simply do 'python <yourscript> > outputfile && less outputfile'. This will store all output in outputfile and use less to navigate through it